# "How to create a long list of strings"

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a long list of deferent stings (3600 strings) so it's painful to do it manually one by one, any ideas?

```
list_1 = ['1' for i in range(3599)]
print(list_1)
```

Comment: what is wrong with your approach? (except that you do not create the correct amount)?

Comment: the result should be look like this :  list_1 = ['1','2',............,'3600']

Comment: `[str(i) for i in range(1, 3601)]`.

Comment: `list_1 = [str(i+1) for i in range(3600)]`

Comment: @NalinDobhal that is less efficient though... (well. just a bit).

Comment: @hiroprotagonist coz I m adding the numbers?

Comment: It was very quick thanks

Comment: @NalinDobhal yes, you have an additional addition per element.

Comment: actually i thought about that but I thought it won't make much difference but I will edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get your desired result you could use

```
list_1 = [str(i) for i in range(1, 3601)]
```